# Type already defines a member called 'this'

Tags: c#

Currently, I am working on a WinForm C# project.
I want to call a serie of combo boxes, with a get set function, however I am getting the following error message:
CS0111  C# Type already defines a member called 'this' with the same parameter types.

```
private ComboBox[] ComboBoxesCoureur;
private ComboBox[] ComboBoxesUitslag; 

ComboBoxesUitslag = new ComboBox[] { cbUitslagCoureur1, cbUitslagCoureur2, cbUitslagCoureur3, cbUitslagCoureur4, cbUitslagCoureur5, cbUitslagCoureur6,
            cbUitslagCoureur7, cbUitslagCoureur8, cbUitslagCoureur9, cbUitslagCoureur10, cbUitslagCoureur11, cbUitslagCoureur12, cbUitslagCoureur13, cbUitslagCoureur14,
            cbUitslagCoureur15, cbUitslagCoureur16, cbUitslagCoureur17, cbUitslagCoureur18, cbUitslagCoureur19, cbUitslagCoureur20 };


ComboBoxesCoureur = new ComboBox[] { cbCoureur1, cbCoureur2, cbCoureur3, cbCoureur4, cbCoureur5, cbCoureur6,
            cbCoureur7, cbCoureur8, cbCoureur9, cbCoureur10, cbCoureur11, cbCoureur12, cbCoureur13, cbCoureur14,
            cbCoureur15, cbCoureur16, cbCoureur17, cbCoureur18, cbCoureur19, cbCoureur20 };

private int[] PuntenID = new int[20];
public int this[int index2]
{
    get => PuntenID[index2];
    set => PuntenID[index2] = value;
}
private int[] PersoonID = new int[20];
public int this[int index]
{
    get => PersoonID[index];
    set => PersoonID[index] = value;
}
```

Does someone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: You've got 2 indexer properties that both take an `int`. This is what is causing the problem. Change one (or both) to methods instead.

Comment: `public int this[int index2]`  and `public int this[int index]` chaging the parameter name from `index` to `index2` is not enought to make it a different signature. What are your trying to achieve? `Myclass[42]` will be accessing `PuntenID` array or `PersoonID` array? How will you know? For this case without more context, i will recommend going for 2 methods `GetPunten(int id)` and `GetPersoon(int id)`.